# How to use JButton in Java

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a hangman game using the Swing class and Graphics class for a APCS class I have.

I created a JButton that would take the guess typed in by the user and either add it to the "misses" or fill in all of the corresponding letters in the word. I have a separate txt file where I pick a random word from.

When I run the program, all of the components show up, but the button does not do anything. I have been working on this for a few days and don't know what I am doing wrong. I have only learnt how to use the Swing class recently, so it may be  a stupid mistake for all I know. I have put all of the code down below.

```
public class Hangman extends JFrame {

    DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    JTextField guess;
    JTextField outputWord;
    JTextField missesString;
    boolean play;
    JButton button = new JButton();
    String output = "";
    String word;
    int misses = 0;

    public Hangman() {
        int again = 0;
        String[] dictionary = new String[1000];
        In words = new In("words.txt");
        JFrame app = new JFrame();
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.setVisible(true);

        app.setSize(500, 500);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            dictionary[i] = words.readLine();
        }
        do {
            int num = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
            word = dictionary[num].toLowerCase();
            String answer = word;
            word = "";
            for (int i = answer.length(); i > 0; i--) {
                word = word + "*";
            }
            int length = answer.length();
            app.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JLabel letter = new JLabel();
            letter.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
            letter.setText("Enter Your guess");
            guess = new JTextField(10);

            JLabel output = new JLabel();
            output.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
            output.setText("The Word is");
            outputWord = new JTextField(30);
            outputWord.setText(word);
            outputWord.setEditable(false);

            JLabel misses = new JLabel();
            misses.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
            misses.setText("Misses:");
            missesString = new JTextField(52);
            missesString.setEditable(false);

            button = new JButton("Guess");
            button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

            JPanel panels = new JPanel();
            panels.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
            panel1.add(letter);
            panel1.add(guess);
            panel1.add(button);

            JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
            panel2.add(output);
            panel2.add(outputWord);

            JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
            panel3.add(misses);
            panel3.add(missesString);

            app.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            app.add(panel2, BorderLayout.EAST);
            app.add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            app.add(panels);

            app.setVisible(true);

            again = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to play again?");
        } while (again == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

    }



    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == guess) {
                output = "";
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= word.length() - 1; i++) {
                if (guess.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(word.substring(i, i + 1))) {
                    output = output.substring(0, i) + guess + output.substring(i + 1, word.length() - 1);
                    outputWord.setText(output);
                } else {
                    misses++;
                    missesString.setText(missesString.getText() + guess + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The components show up perfectly on the screen, it is only the button that is giving me a hard time by not working as expected.

Comment: When you say "not working as expected" does that mean the button action does something, just not what you wanted, or that it does nothing at all?

Comment: Does switching `output.substring(0,i) + guess + ...` to `output.substring(0,i) + guess.getText() + ...` fix it?

Comment: Also might need that in the `missesString.setText` part. I am fairly certain `JTextFields` can't be concatenated to strings.

Comment: ButtonListener.actionPerformed() is getting called when the button is pressed, so the JButton is setup correctly and working correctly. Whatever you are (not) seeing must be a flaw in the logic... but the question title is about JButton.

Comment: This is definitely a good place for a debugger or for a couple of println statements in that action listener, just to prove that what you think is happening really is. Note that you are making the button twice, once at the top and once in the constructor--this doesn't affect anything, but it probably isn't your intent.